# Issue while loading world map in libgdx

Tags: java, opengl, graphics, maps, libgdx

I used one single image and created complete world map using this image (tile.png of 128X128). I am following this [tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/GraphicsTileMapsOld#Loading_a_tile_map).
I am able to load files properly, but unfortunately not able to see any world map. There must be some thing i am missing.

Can someone help understand what should i do to make things right?

There is one .tmx file created from single image named tile.png which is mentioned below (Used Tile Map packer tool):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<map version="1.0" orientation="orthogonal" width="8" height="8" tilewidth="128"   tileheight="128">
 <tileset firstgid="1" name="tile" tilewidth="128" tileheight="128">
  <image source="tile.png" width="128" height="128"/>
 </tileset>
 <layer name="Tile Layer 1" width="8" height="8">
  <data encoding="base64" compression="zlib">
   eJxjZGBgYBzBGAAhgABB
 </data>
</layer>
```

I have a pack file with data (which pointed to tile.png file):

```
tile.png
format: RGBA8888
filter: Nearest,Nearest
repeat: none
tile
  rotate: false
  xy: 0, 0
  size: 128, 128
  orig: 128, 128
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
```

I am using code in create():

```
TiledMap tiledMap = TiledLoader.createMap(Gdx.files.internal("tile.tmx"));
FileHandle handle = Gdx.files.internal("tilepack");
TileAtlas tileAtlas = new TileAtlas(tiledMap, handle);
tileMapRenderer = new TileMapRenderer(tiledMap, tileAtlas, 8, 8);
```

and in render :
    tileMapRenderer.render(camera);

As per above mentioned tutorial everything seems to be fine.

Also to add, i have created complete world map of 1024X1024 using single tile of 128X128. Hope that is fine or do i need separate tiles?

Here is the render method:

```
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 1, 1); 
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); 
camera.update(); 
tileMapRenderer.render(camera);
```

Comment: which version of libgdx you are using

Comment: I am on latest version of libgdx 0.9.8. Also i am seeing that all files are getting loaded, but no map is coming on screen.

Comment: do you render it in the render method? Show us some more code of it... just creating the render does not show the picture...

Comment: Hey Benn, my render code doesn't have much code, i am making background to some color and then updating camera and finally trying to draw map. I thing this should work as i am doing nothing in this. Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 1, 1);
  Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  camera.update();
  tileMapRenderer.render(camera);

Comment: if you change the clearcolor do you see a different colour? and did you try to not use  Tileatlas? You can simply put the tmx file into the same folder as the Tilesets and just use the regular loader. Maybe there is something wrong you never know about it. try using the `TmxMapLoader`.

Comment: switch your code to libgdx nigtlies .... many of the bug are fixed in that version... and it is easier to use tile map in libgdx nightlies 0.9.9